# Bind NavigateUri property of HyperlinkButton Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I am parsing some JSON data using Newtonsoft.NET for my WP8 app in C#/XAML and everything works fine except the binding of NavigationUri to the HyperlinkButton. Here is the DataTemplate of my databound LongListSelector:

```
<DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 20" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieTitle }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ImdbCode }" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding ImdbLink}">View on IMDB</HyperlinkButton>
<Image Source="{Binding MovieCover}" Width="300" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ImdbLink}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This way everything is loaded correctly but the HyperLinkButton doesn't navigate to the Uri.

What should I do to make sure the navigation works? 
If it is not possible with HyperLinkButton then can I add a regular button to which I could pass the url so that OnClick event can navigate to url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the url is correct the webbrowser can be activated like this:

XAML

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding ImdbLink}" 
                 Click="NavigateButton_Click">View on IMDB</HyperlinkButton>
```

C#

```
private void NavigateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hyperlinkButton = sender as HyperlinkButton;
    if(hyperlinkButton == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    ShowInBrowser(hyperlinkButton.NavigateUri);
}

private void ShowInBrowser(Uri url)
{
    Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask wbt = 
        new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask();
    wbt.Uri = url;
    wbt.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have no `RequestNavigate` method. Try:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding ImdbLink}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">View on IMDB</HyperlinkButton>
```

and in your code behind for the view put

```
    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

or however you want to deal with that click event (i.e. open a new webview with that as the url)